# How to improve my British accent, in particular intonation

Tags: british-english, accent

I have been studying English for many years, focusing on British accent. Apart from my books with DVDs in British, I listen to different podcasts of BBC learning English. Sometimes, I shadow the speaker to repeat it with the same pace and intonation. However, I assume that while I speak, my intonation is not good enough perhaps because we dont have much rising or falling in our language.

I have noticed that there are lots of great books, DVDs, websites with the title "American accent training", which are not merely about pronunciation, but also about intonation and everything. However, I could not find such a comprehensive thing about British accent. Could you please recommend some ways, books, and stuff to improve my accent?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read:

Barbara Bird: *A Course in English Intonation (Received Pronunciation)*

The book was published in 1997, but still can be bought. Unfortunately, the accompanying audio material is only available on cassettes. Still, the book may provide you some background and let you know what you need to pay attention to.

For what it's worth, it can be [read online for free](http://urn.nb.no/URN:NBN:no-nb_digibok_2009022304090) on the website of the National Library of Norway. Unfortunately, the access is restricted to Norwegian IP addresses, but you can always try to use a proxy.